# Как передать переменную в format?

Tags: python, format

Как в python передать переменную на место "2" в конструкцию `format`?

```
print("{0:.2f}".format(7.18345))
```

Чтобы было типа такого:

```
print("{0:.(a)f}".format(7.18345))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Язык в format-шаблоне](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) поддерживает вложенные подстановки:

```
print("{:.{precision}f}".format(7.18345, precision=2))
# -> 7.18
```

Comment: Работает :) Благодарю.