# Как вывести маленькие числа в привычном виде (0.00002), вместо 2e-05?

Tags: python

Мне необходимо в выражении, например:

```
print (2/100000)
```

получить на выходе 0.00002, а не 2e-05?!

С функциями `float` или `round(x,8)` тоже самое выходит.
Уточню, необходимо округление до 8 знаков после запятой.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как передать переменную в format?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604565/23044)

Answer (score 1):

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 10
Decimal(2)/Decimal(100000)
```

Comment: Как-то совсем уж костыльненько

Comment: Почему же? `str(Decimal(2)/Decimal(100000))` - само то

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вывести число с плавающей точкой в фиксированном формате с указанным числом знаков после запятой:

```
>>> '%.8f' % 2e-5
'0.00002000'
```

Если как переменные заданы:

```
>>> n = 2e-5
>>> precision = 8
>>> f'{n:.{precision}f}'
'0.00002000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Так пойдет?

```
 '%0.5f' % (2/100000)
```

Предлагаю ещё вот такую функцию

```
def fixed_num(n, prec=0):
    return f"{n:.{prec}f}"

fixed_num(2/100000, 5)
'0.00002'
```

[PEP 498: Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)

---

Воспользовавшись идеей из соседнего ответа, можно определить функцию отображающую максимально возможное количество знаков без "научной нотации":

```
import decimal
ctx = decimal.Context()

# prec - precision - количество значащих знаков, не округление до знака
def float_to_str(f, prec = 18): # 18 знаков хватит всем (c) BG
    ctx.prec = prec
    d1 = ctx.create_decimal(repr(f))
    return format(d1, 'f')

>>> float_to_str(2/100000)
'0.00002'
>>> float_to_str(7/130000)
'0.00005384615384615385'
>>> float_to_str(7/130000)
'0.000053846154'
# округлять до знака нужно заранее
>>> float_to_str(round(7/23, 8))
'0.30434783'
```

Comment: А если с максимальной точностью с отбрасыыанием незначащих нулей?

Comment: Хм, а 1/30000 как выводить?

Comment: Как точность типа float позволяет, так и выводить)

Comment: т.е. оригинальное выражение должно выглядеть как `0.00002000000000000000163606107828062619091724627651274204254150390625`? Кому это нужно? =)

Comment: Ага, автор уточнил про 8 знаков после запятой. Тогда отстану от вас)

Comment: @andreymal, последнее решение вроде удовлетворяет вашим запросам?

Comment: Decimal по-моему костыль, но по результату да :)